# Create virtual network interface in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm attempting to create a virtual network interface in Ubuntu 16.04, specifically a copy of the wifi interface.

In the past all I've had to do was run this command: `sudo ifconfig wlan0:0 192.168.1.3` and the new interface `wlan0:0` was created with a static IP address. On my current install this command works with the ethernet interface (named `eno1`), but nothing happens when I try it with the wifi interface (named `wlx08863b02e256`). After attempting with the wifi interface name no error message is shown, but running `ifconfig` doesn't show a new interface either.

I'm needing to do this because a tool I'm trying to use needs to access multiple IP addresses, more IP addresses than there are network interfaces available.

Are there alternative methods of creating virtual network interfaces in Ubuntu 16.04? Or am I doing something wrong with the wifi interface?

Comment: Have you tried just adding the extra IP address to the WiFi interface?  In a lot of cases, you don't actually need a virtual interface.  You probably will have to use the `ip` command to do that though, because `ifconfig` still behaves oddly when dealing with multiple addresses.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in multiple answers on this site before, `wlan:0` is not a "virtual interface" - it's the old way for `ifconfig` of assigning multiple IP addresses. With more modern tools like `ip`, you just assign multiple IP addresses with `ip addr add ..` to the same interface. It will also list all address from `ifconfig`'s `wlan:0`, `wlan:1` etc. under `wlan`, because that's how modern Linux kernels store them internally.

Note that working with multiple IP addresses can be a PITA, because you have to make sure all your applications bind to the correct address. Not all applications are able to do this. You didn't say what the tool you are trying to use is, and how it wants to make use of those addresses.

There are multiple other ways to create *real* virtual network interfaces, in case your tool really needs multiple interfaces, and not just multiple IP addresses. Which way to use depends on what the tool needs.